# How to select data from SQL Server based on data available in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I have a list of data in one of the pandas dataframe column for which I want to query SQL Server database. Is there any way I can query a SQL Server DB based on data I have in pandas dataframe.

select * from table_name where customerid in pd.dataframe.customerid

In SAP, there is something called "For all entries in" where the SQL can query the DB based on the data available in the array, I was trying to find something similar.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example and show what you have tried; see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with tiny DataFrame, then the easiest way would be to generate a corresponding SQL:

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]:
   id  val
0   1   21
1   3  111
2   5   34
3  12   76

In [9]: q = 'select * from tab where id in ({})'.format(','.join(['?']*len(df['id'])))

In [10]: q
Out[10]: 'select * from tab where id in (?,?,?,?)'
```

now you can read data from SQL Server:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
conn = create_engine(...)
new = pd.read_sql(q, conn, params=tuple(df['id']))
```

NOTE: this approach will not work for bigger DF's as the generated query (and/or list of bind variables) might bee too long either for Pandas `to_sql()` function or for SQL Server or even for both.

---

For bigger DFs I would recommend to write your pandas DF to SQL Server table and then use SQL subquery to filter needed data:

```
df[list_of_columns_to_save].to_sql('tmp_tab_name', conn, index=False)
q = "select * from tab where id in (select id from tmp_tab_name)"
new = pd.read_sql(q, conn, if_exists='replace')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very familiar scenario and one can use the below code to Query SQL using a very large pandas dataframe. The parameter n needs to be manipulated based on your SQL server memory. For me n=25000 worked.

```
n = 25000  #chunk row size
## Big_frame dataframe divided into smaller chunks of n into a list 
list_df = [big_frame[i:i+n] for i in range(0,big_frame.shape[0],n)] 
## Create another dataframe with columns names as expected from SQL
big_frame_2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=[<Mention all column names from SQL>]) 
## Print total no. of iterations
print("Total Iterations:", len(list_df)) 
for i in range(0,len(list_df)):
    print("Iteration :",i) 
    temp_frame = list_df[i] 
    testList = temp_frame['customer_no'] 
## Pass smaller chunk of data to SQL(here I am passing a list of customers)
    temp_DF = SQL_Query(tuple(testList)) 
    print(temp_DF.shape[0]) 
## Append all the data retrieved from SQL to big_frame_2
big_frame_2=big_frame_2.append(temp_DF, ignore_index=True)
```