# Selecting rows from sql if they are also in a dataframe

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I have a MS sql server with a lot of rows( around 4 million) from all the customers and their information.
I can also get a list of phone numbers of all visitors of my website in a given timeframe that I can get in a csv file and then covert to a dataframe in python. What I want to do is to select two columns from my server(one is the phone number and the other one is a property of that person) but I only want to select this records from people who are in both my dataframe and my server.
What I currently do is selecting all customers from sql server and then merge them with my dataframe. But obviously this is not very fast. Is there any way to do this faster?

```
query2 = """
SELECT encrypt_phone, col2
FROM DatabaseTable
    """
cursor.execute(query2)
tables = cursor.fetchall()
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(tables, columns=[x[0] for x in cursor.description])
df1.merge(df2, how='inner', indicator=True)
```

Comment: what's the current `df1.index.size` ?

Comment: what does exactly takes time ? ```cursor.fetchall()```, ```from_records``` or ```merge``` ?

Comment: df1.index.size is around 150K

Comment: "records from people" - what's the column indicating that `people`?

Answer (score 0):

If your *DataFrame* have not many rows, I would do it the simple way as [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48310212/16120011) :

```
V = df["colx"].unique()

Q = 'SELECT encrypt_phone, col2 FROM DatabaseTable WHERE coly IN ({})'.format(','.join(['?']*len(V)))

cursor.execute(Q, tuple(V))
tables = cursor.fetchall()

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(tables, columns=[x[0] for x in cursor.description])
```

NB : `colx` and `coly` are the columns that refer to the customers (*id, or name, ..*) in the pandas DataFrame and in the SQL table, respectively.

Otherwise, you may need to store `df1` as a table in your DB and then perform a [*sub-query*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver16) :

```
df1.to_sql('DataFrameTable', conn, index=False) #this will store df1 in the DB

Q = "SELECT encrypt_phone, col2 FROM DatabaseTable WHERE coly IN (SELECT colx FROM DataFrameTable)"

df2 = pd.read_sql_query(Q, conn)
```

Comment: what is considered not many rows? like how many rows can this handle?

Comment: Can you `print(len(V))` ? Is it _150K_ ? Have you tried running the code ?

Comment: its telling me that it can only support 2100 parameters. 
"The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters"
How do I do the subquery?

Comment: Then, go for option 2.

Comment: Can you also share the code for the second option?

Comment: I updated my answser, you can try an approach like that.